# amplify_flutter any which doesn't exist (could not find package amplify_flutter at https://pub.dartlang.org),

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, aws-amplify, amplify-flutter

I am trying implement amplify-flutter from this document but when i run pub get it showing "depends on amplify_flutter any which doesn't exist (could not find package amplify_flutter at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed."
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/blob/master/example/pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

You can use `amplify_flutter` from github!

```
dependencies:
  amplify_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter.git
      path: packages/amplify_flutter
```